# Portable Frame-Rate Counter

Tags: windows, portable

Looking for a **portable** frame-rate (FPS) counter that works on *Windows 10 (64-bit)* and is compatible with *DirectX 12* games and video players.

Preferably in a standalone (single-`EXE`) distribution but PortableApps Format (PAF) is also fine.

Hence **portable**:

1. Configurations should be saved in working directory instead of `ProgramData`, registry or local/roaming `AppData`.
2. No left-behind files. If drivers or `DLL`s are required to run, [re]register them when executed and de-register them when done.
3. Preferably no administrative privilege request and no modify to system files.

Thanks in advance.